# How do I efficiently limit the time of a function (anytime algorithm) in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, minimax

I want to use depth-first search to solve a minimax problem; however, so that my algorithm can complete and always have a solution, I'm using iterative DFS (so find all nodes one layer deep, then two, then three). I'd like to be able to interrupt the searching after a certain amount of time has passed, however, I cannot seem to find a good way other than to either turn my recursive algorithm into an iterative one with a stack and check the time every loop (which seems inefficient) or pass the ending time into all recursive calls and checking at the beginning of each call (which seems even more inefficient and even more complex than the iterative).

I'd prefer not to use any additional libraries other than the Java 8 source.

Pseudocode:

```
function negamax(node, depth, α, β, color)
    if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
        return color * the heuristic value of node
    bestValue := -∞
    childNodes := GenerateMoves(node)
    childNodes := OrderMoves(childNodes)
    foreach child in childNodes
        val := -negamax(child, depth - 1, -β, -α, -color)
        bestValue := max( bestValue, val )
        α := max( α, val )
        if α ≥ β
            break
    return bestValue

function search()
    depth := 0
    bestValue := null
    while (++depth > 0) // runs forever until interrupted
        bestValue := negamax( rootNode, depth, -∞, +∞, 1)
    return bestValue

function main()
    search();
```

Comment: Could you show your code? Then it would be easier to contrive some specific solution. I'd offer to extend Thread.class (or implement Runnable interface) and use interruption mechanism.

Comment: I'd go with @Battle_Slug: use a standard task cancelling mechanism (in C# that would be CancellationToken, not too sure about Java) and let a second thread (timer) cancel the operation after a certain time.

Comment: I don't actually have any code at the moment, but I'll add in some pseudocode.

Comment: You can use an [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) as a flag that must trigger the algorithm to stop. Check the flag on each run. If it is true, stop the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Multi-threading concept.

eg:

```
Thread tempThread = new Thread("tempThread");
Thread originalThread = new Thread("DFSthread");
public void run() //run() of tempThread
{ 
 try{
      tempThread.sleep(1000); //you can add the limit you want here
      originalThread.stop();
}
catch(InterruptedException exc)
{
   System.out.println(exc);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `stop` has been [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). `sleep` does not guarantee that 1000 ms have passed since time slices can be given to other threads. You're better off calculating the timing elsewhere.